# Heater not working 1999 Hyundai Elantra

Tags: heater

I took out the radio to change a fuse and had to take out the  heater/ac panel and now the heat does not work

Comment: Need more info on "heat does not work." Does the heater fan come on but only blows cold air, or does the fan not come on at all?

Comment: Dumb question:  Are you sure you plugged the wires for the heater knob back in before putting the heater/AC panel back on?